# WebPage caching in Hazelcast

Tags: caching, ehcache, hazelcast

We are currently using ehcache : SimplePageCachingFilter to perform webpage caching.

Now we have decided to move on to Hazelcast for our caching and i couldn't find any information related to Web Page caching in HazelCast documentation.

Does Hazel cast support Web Caching?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes most definitely.

Hazelcast has many modes of support for web caching...

http://www.hazelcast.org/use-cases/caching/

I assume you are interested in the distributed cache? Hazelcast can be used as a form of elastic Memcached and it supports that protocol natively.

Or you can work more closely with the application and can use it has a Hibernate L2 cache or within spring as a spring cache.

If you explain more about what you're trying to do, it's likely that Hazelcast can be used to achieve that, as Caching is a core use case for Hazelcast.

Comment: Hi Miko thanks for the response but in the link you provided i dont see any reference to web caching , using ehcaches :SimplePageCachingFilter is being used to cache web pages, i want to see if we have similar provisioning in hazelcast

Comment: Hi Remo... sorry for the delay in answering. Hazelcast isn't "pin compatible" with EhCache, but we support common caching standard APIs like JCache and Hibernate. We would expect users to pick between Ehcache which is more specialized for local cache and Hazelcast which is more specialized for distributed cache. Greg Luck, the author of EhCache is CEO at Hazelcast.